# Failed to open and upload big image file, map_file and map_server

Tags: navigation, 2d-image, ros-kinetic, pgm, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, I am trying to upload a map file for map_server and use it for navigation and amcl localization, but it is really big, 25500 x 5300 pixels (.pgm). The map_server is not starting and shows this message:

```
[ERROR] [1556905481.419883442]: failed to open image file "/home/dev/src/robot/navigation/maps/bigger_map.pgm": Out of memory
```

Is possible to use a map with a big number of pixels or I need to reduce the number of pixels to work well?
Is it depends on computer memory RAM?

I have tried to use in .png file format, but the message was the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322439/failed-to-open-and-upload-big-image-file,-map_file-and-map_server/) by [Lucas Marins](https://answers.ros.org/users/38409/lucas-marins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-04**:
I'm not into navigation at all, but 25500 x 5300 == 135150000 bytes (approx 128MB). And that is just if each cell only occupies a single byte (which is probably not the case). High resolution maps *could* be an issue. Do things work if you subsample the map? Otherwise I'd suggest to search for some previous Q&As about map resolution and related problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found out that the map_server uses SDL_image to read image files and dimensions are limited to 8192 x 8192 == 67108864 pixels, approximately half of my map.
There is also a one-year open issue in ros-planning GitHub repository.
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/635
Until now, the best solution is to divide the map to some small maps or sections and write a map switcher node to manage it.

---

Originally posted by [Lucas Marins](https://answers.ros.org/users/38409/lucas-marins/) with karma: 71 on 2019-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0